# retrieve the folder name of the immediate parent

Tags: asp.net

Is there any method in the File, Directory, FileInfo, Path etc classes
| that makes it easy to retrieve the folder name of the immediate parent
| folder of a file

Comment: You should accept some answers from your other questions first.

Answer (score 0):

[`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) would appear to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the DirectoryName using the following Code

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo objInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Request.PhysicalPath);
String strDirectoryName = objInfo.Name;
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.